# jQuery reorder list items based on class

Tags: jquery, list, html-lists

Is there a simple way to reorder my list items using a class?

I want to specify a class to feature those items at the top of the list first, with other list items listed below.

```
<ul class="order-me">
    <li class="">normal content</li>
    <li class="">normal content</li>
    <li class="featured">featured content</li>
    <li class="">normal content</li>
    <li class="featured">featured content</li>
    <li class="">normal content</li>
    <li class="">normal content</li>
</ul>
```

**Desired output:**

```
<ul class="order-me">
    <li class="featured">featured content</li>
    <li class="featured">featured content</li>
    <li class="">normal content</li>
    <li class="">normal content</li>
    <li class="">normal content</li>
    <li class="">normal content</li>
    <li class="">normal content</li>
</ul>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can prepend the `.featured` elements to their containing `ul` to move them to the top of the list. Try this:

```js
$('.featured').prependTo('.order-me');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="order-me">
  <li class="">normal content</li>
  <li class="">normal content</li>
  <li class="featured">featured content</li>
  <li class="">normal content</li>
  <li class="featured">featured content</li>
  <li class="">normal content</li>
  <li class="">normal content</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Wow, suck me sideways that was easier than I thought. Thank you Rory!

Comment: jQuery usually is :D Glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

To add to @Rory McCrossan's answer, I've added the ability to sort it with navigation buttons

```
$("ul.order-nav li").click(function() {
  // Find the Data attribute from unordered list [.order-nav]
  var sortClass = '.' + $(this).data('sort-by');
  // Prepent the [li] with matching class to top of [ul]
  $(sortClass).prependTo('.order-me');
});
```

[**Here is the Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3ue11tek/8/)

Comment: Late to the party, but a nice addition, I like it. Cheers.