# Reorder list with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a list that goes

```
<li>product 1</li>
<li>product 2</li>
<li>product 3</li>
<li>product 4</li>
<li>product 5</li>
<li>product 6</li>
<li>product 7</li>
<li>product 8</li>
<li>quickview 1</li>
<li>quickview 2</li>
<li>quickview 3</li>
<li>quickview 4</li>
<li>quickview 5</li>
<li>quickview 6</li>
<li>quickview 7</li>
<li>quickview 8</li>
```

and I need to reorder the HTML bits so it displays

```
<li>product 1</li>
<li>product 2</li>
<li>product 3</li>
<li>product 4</li>
<li>quickview 1</li>
<li>quickview 2</li>
<li>quickview 3</li>
<li>quickview 4</li>
<li>product 5</li>
<li>product 6</li>
<li>product 7</li>
<li>product 8</li>
<li>quickview 5</li>
<li>quickview 6</li>
<li>quickview 7</li>
<li>quickview 8</li>
```

and so on...

is there any way to do this with classes? It needs to auto detect every 4 product elements and bring the 4 corresponding quickviews under it.

I created a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/q42wwqbh/2/) using

```
$('.quickview').appendTo('.last');
```

(thanks to the answer to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25804721/jquery-reorder-list-items-based-on-class)) and adding a class "last" to every fourth product li. I'm sure there's an easy way to do this with jquery but it escapes me.

Would greatly appreciate any help! :) Thank you!

Comment: do you know count of product and quickview?

Comment: I don't.. this is actually from my shopify store, and the lists are generated with a snippet.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [slice](http://api.jquery.com/slice/), [after](http://api.jquery.com/after/) and [each](http://api.jquery.com/each/) functions like

```
$('.last').each(function(index,el){
    $(this).after($('.quickview').slice(index*4,(index+1)*4));
});
```

```js
var quickviews = $('.order-me .quickview');
$('.order-me .last').each(function(index, el) {
  $(this).after( //insert after current element
    quickviews.slice(index * 4, (index + 1) * 4) //get part from quickviews for current element
  );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="order-me">
  <li>product 1</li>
  <li>product 2</li>
  <li>product 3</li>
  <li class="last">product 4</li>
  <li>product 5</li>
  <li>product 6</li>
  <li>product 7</li>
  <li class="last">product 8</li>
  <li>product 9</li>
  <li>product 10</li>
  <li>product 11</li>
  <li class="last">product 12</li>
  <li class="quickview">quickview 1</li>
  <li class="quickview">quickview 2</li>
  <li class="quickview">quickview 3</li>
  <li class="quickview">quickview 4</li>
  <li class="quickview">quickview 5</li>
  <li class="quickview">quickview 6</li>
  <li class="quickview">quickview 7</li>
  <li class="quickview">quickview 8</li>
  <li class="quickview">quickview 9</li>
  <li class="quickview">quickview 10</li>
  <li class="quickview">quickview 11</li>
  <li class="quickview">quickview 12</li>
</ul>
```