# PHP - Move content to the bottom of list when checked the checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I want to make a multiple User Agreement, that user must check the checkbox one by one. When a user checked content number 1, then content number 2 will move to the top of the list, and content number 1 will be dropped from the list.

So, the problem is, when user check the checkbox, the content is not moving.

Can someone help me to make moving content when checkbox is checked.

here's my script :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#form").validate();
  });
function showAmanat1(){
    if(document.form.amanat1.checked)
         { document.form.amanat2.disabled=false; } 
    else { for (var i=2; i<14; i++)             
           { var amanatx="amanat"+i;
                 document.forms.form[amanatx].checked=false;
                 document.forms.form[amanatx].disabled=true;
           }
         }
}
function showAmanat2(){     
    if(document.form.amanat2.checked)
         {  document.form.amanat3.disabled=false} 
    else { for (var i=3; i<14; i++)             
           { var amanatx="amanat"+i;
                 document.forms.form[amanatx].checked=false;
                 document.forms.form[amanatx].disabled=true;
           }
         }
} 
function showAmanat3(){     
    if(document.form.amanat3.checked)
         {  document.form.amanat4.disabled=false} 
    else { for (var i=4; i<14; i++)             
           { var amanatx="amanat"+i;
                 document.forms.form[amanatx].checked=false;
                 document.forms.form[amanatx].disabled=true;
           }
         }
}  
function showAmanat4(){     
    if(document.form.amanat4.checked)
         {  document.form.amanat5.disabled=false} 
    else { for (var i=5; i<14; i++)             
           { var amanatx="amanat"+i;
                 document.forms.form[amanatx].checked=false;
                 document.forms.form[amanatx].disabled=true;
           }
         }
}  
function showAmanat5(){     
    if(document.form.amanat5.checked)
         {  document.form.amanat6.disabled=false} 
    else { for (var i=6; i<14; i++)             
           { var amanatx="amanat"+i;
                 document.forms.form[amanatx].checked=false;
                 document.forms.form[amanatx].disabled=true;
           }
         }
} 
function showAmanat6(){     
    if(document.form.amanat6.checked)
         {  document.form.amanat7.disabled=false} 
    else { for (var i=7; i<14; i++)             
           { var amanatx="amanat"+i;
                 document.forms.form[amanatx].checked=false;
                 document.forms.form[amanatx].disabled=true;
           }
         }
} 
function showAmanat7(){     
    if(document.form.amanat7.checked)
         {  document.form.amanat8.disabled=false} 
    else { for (var i=8; i<14; i++)             
           { var amanatx="amanat"+i;
                 document.forms.form[amanatx].checked=false;
                 document.forms.form[amanatx].disabled=true;
           }
         }
} 
function showAmanat8(){     
    if(document.form.amanat8.checked)
         {  document.form.amanat9.disabled=false} 
    else { for (var i=9; i<14; i++)             
           { var amanatx="amanat"+i;
                 document.forms.form[amanatx].checked=false;
                 document.forms.form[amanatx].disabled=true;
           }
         }
} 
function showAmanat9(){     
    if(document.form.amanat9.checked)
         {  document.form.amanat10.disabled=false} 
    else { for (var i=10; i<14; i++)                
           { var amanatx="amanat"+i;
                 document.forms.form[amanatx].checked=false;
                 document.forms.form[amanatx].disabled=true;
           }
         }
} 
function showAmanat10(){    
    if(document.form.amanat10.checked)
         {  document.form.amanat11.disabled=false} 
    else { for (var i=11; i<14; i++)                
           { var amanatx="amanat"+i;
                 document.forms.form[amanatx].checked=false;
                 document.forms.form[amanatx].disabled=true;
           }
         }
} 
function showAmanat11(){    
    if(document.form.amanat11.checked)
         {  document.form.amanat12.disabled=false} 
    else { for (var i=12; i<14; i++)                
           { var amanatx="amanat"+i;
                 document.forms.form[amanatx].checked=false;
                 document.forms.form[amanatx].disabled=true;
           }
         }
} 
function showAmanat12(){    
    if(document.form.amanat12.checked)
         {  document.form.amanat13.disabled=false} 
    else { for (var i=13; i<14; i++)                
           { var amanatx="amanat"+i;
                 document.forms.form[amanatx].checked=false;
                 document.forms.form[amanatx].disabled=true;
           }
         }
}
function showPernyataan(){  
    if(document.form.amanat13.checked)
         { document.form.c1.disabled=false;
           document.form.c2.disabled=false;} 
    else { document.form.c1.checked=false; document.form.c2.checked=false;
           document.form.c1.disabled=true; document.form.c2.disabled=true; }
} 
</script>
<form id="form" name="form" method='POST'> 
<tr>
       <td align="justify" colspan="2"> 
        <ol id="point">
          <li>If this checkbox is checked, then the next checkbox should be appeared in top of list and the checked one is in bottom of list or dissapear.
          </li><label class='agreement_label'><strong>I Agree <span class='red_style'>*)</span></strong><input name="amanat1" type="checkbox" class="required agreement" onchange="showAmanat1()"/></label>
          <li>dummy for 2 </li><label class='agreement_label'><strong>I Agree<span class='red_style'>*)</span></strong><input name='amanat2' type='checkbox' class='required agreement' onchange='showAmanat2()' disabled="disabled"/></label>
<li>dummy for 3</li><label class='agreement_label'><strong>I Agree <span class='red_style'>*)</span></strong><input name='amanat3' type='checkbox' class='required agreement' onchange='showAmanat3()'disabled="disabled"/></label>
<li>dummy for 4</li><label class='agreement_label'><strong>I Agree <span class='red_style'>*)</span></strong><input name='amanat4' type='checkbox' class='required agreement' onchange='showAmanat4()' disabled="disabled"/></label>
<li>dummy for 5</li><label class='agreement_label'><strong>I Agree <span class='red_style'>*)</span></strong><input name='amanat5' type='checkbox' class='required agreement' onchange='showAmanat5()' disabled="disabled"/></label>
<li>dummy for 6</li><label class='agreement_label'><strong>I Agree <span class='red_style'>*)</span></strong><input name='amanat6' type='checkbox' class='required agreement' onchange='showAmanat6()' disabled="disabled"/></label>
<li>dummy for 7</li><label class='agreement_label'><strong>I Agree<span class='red_style'>*)</span></strong><input name='amanat7' type='checkbox' class='required agreement' onchange='showAmanat7()' disabled="disabled"/></label>
<li>dummy for 8</li><label class='agreement_label'><strong>I Agree <span class='red_style'>*)</span></strong><input name='amanat8' type='checkbox' class='required agreement' onchange='showAmanat8()' disabled="disabled"/></label>
<li>dummy for 9</li><label class='agreement_label'><strong>I Agree<span class='red_style'>*)</span></strong><input name='amanat9' type='checkbox' class='required agreement' onchange='showAmanat9()' disabled="disabled"/></label>
<li>dummy for 10</li><label class='agreement_label'><strong>I Agree <span class='red_style'>*)</span></strong><input name='amanat10' type='checkbox' class='required agreement' onchange='showAmanat10()' disabled="disabled"/></label>
<li>dummy for 11</li><label class='agreement_label'><strong>I Agree <span class='red_style'>*)</span></strong><input name='amanat11' type='checkbox' class='required agreement' onchange='showAmanat11()' disabled="disabled"/></label>
<li>dummy for 12</li><label class='agreement_label'><strong>I Agree<span class='red_style'>*)</span></strong><input name='amanat12' type='checkbox' class='required agreement' onchange='showAmanat12()' disabled="disabled"/></label>
<li>dummy for 13</li><label class='agreement_label'><strong>I Agree <span class='red_style'>*)</span></strong><input name='amanat13' type='checkbox' class='required agreement' onchange='showPernyataan()' disabled="disabled"/></label>                   
        </ol>
      </td>
    </tr>    
</table>     
</form>
</div>
```

and heres my fiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/a6ea9yhL/5/

Comment: it wil easy if you hide the checked one

Comment: how to make it hidden sir ? i tried to hidden the checked one still not working based on my script @AdarshMohan

Comment: add `document.form.amanat1.hidden = true;` to hide the choice box

Comment: Instead of hiding, I disabled : https://jsfiddle.net/a6ea9yhL/7/ Also minimized your code functionality

Comment: that's not what I mean @myway, i want to make multiple checbox user agreement move to the bottom if checked.

Answer (score 0):

> Hiding the element is easy

I would suggest you to put each point in a span and give that span an id like below:

```
<span id="amanat2">
  <li>dummy for 2 </li>
  <label class='agreement_label'>
    <strong>I Agree<span class='red_style'>*)</span></strong>
    <input name='amanat2' type='checkbox' class='required agreement' onchange='showAmanat2()' disabled="disabled"/>
  </label>
</span>
```

Then in if block of your functions add

```
document.getElementById('amanat2').style.display = 'none'; // chnage the id
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code's strategy has to be changed, rather than fixed!
Why don't you reorder the list each time the user check an item, for example, initiate all the checkboxs as list elements, with a specific class: "vergin", and on each click, reorder the list according to the function: .prepend()
Follow the link for more details:

[jQuery reorder list items based on class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25804721/jquery-reorder-list-items-based-on-class)

Comment: yea i should replace my script with the new one.
thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

Try this script. This script will move clicked list to the bottom of the list

```
  <ul>
    <li id="1">1</li>
<li id="2">2</li>
<li id="3">3</li>
<li id="4">4</li>
<li id="5">5</li>
<li id="6">6</li>
<li id="7">7</li>
</ul>

$("li").click(function(){
  $(this).appendTo('ul');
});
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is what you want

```js
function clickCheckBox(elem){
  document.getElementById('agreement').appendChild(elem);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol id="agreement">
  <li onclick="clickCheckBox(this);">Agreement * <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-item" /></li>
  <li onclick="clickCheckBox(this);">Agreement * <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-item" /></li>
  <li onclick="clickCheckBox(this);">Agreement * <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-item" /></li>
  <li onclick="clickCheckBox(this);">Agreement * <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-item" /></li>
  <li onclick="clickCheckBox(this);">Agreement * <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-item" /></li>
  <li onclick="clickCheckBox(this);">Agreement * <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-item" /></li>
</ol>
<div class="div-1"></div>
```

Comment: its will be good if the number and content also moving to the bottom if checked.

Comment: the number will always remain serialized because of the default nature of LI, the data will flow down, else you will have to specify the number with the content and disable the labelling of li using css